# Is there a way to create Github Actions variables using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to create Github actions variables using Terraform, I can create Actions secrets easily by using `github_actions_environment_secret` resource. I need to use variables not secrets sometimes because I need to reveal the value of the variable.

I searched for a resource to create Actions variables on Terraform registry.terraform.io, but I only found resources to create Action secrets like `github_actions_environment_secret` and not Actions variables.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform? If yes, see this issue https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/35 and its PR https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/pull/79 (not merged yet in the docs).

Comment: Variables are so new that this feature doesn't appear to be implemented yet. See this issue: https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/1479

Comment: @aknosis Exactly, the feature Configuration variables is new to Github as I discovered in this Article (https://github.blog/2023-01-10-introducing-required-workflows-and-configuration-variables-to-github-actions/) dating to 10/1/2023.

Comment: @Azeem no I'm not using (https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform). I'm using `integrations/github` (https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github). The feature Configuration variables has just been introduced. Hope Integrations/github will create an equivalent Terraform resource soon.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [go-github support](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/1479#issuecomment-1432911407), you could use a Terraform module like [`cloud-native-toolkit/terraform-util-clis`](https://github.com/cloud-native-toolkit/terraform-util-clis) which can install the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/manual/).

The latest release of that CLI, [gh v2.25.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.25.0), includes [`gh variable`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_variable) commands, including [`gh variable set`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_variable_set)

```bash
# Read variable value from an environment variable
$ gh variable set MYVARIABLE --body "$ENV_VALUE"

# Read variable value from a file
$ gh variable set MYVARIABLE < myfile.txt

# Set variable for a deployment environment in the current repository
$ gh variable set MYVARIABLE --env myenvironment
```